# How can I resolve Nginx websocket connection error?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy my React app to AWS EC2(Ubuntu Server 22.04) and assign custom domain to it.
Everything's working fine.
I've installed node.js on EC2 and made it as a service.
Also, I've installed Nginx and configured it for my custom domain.

[image]

And if I visit https://www.aitechly.com, everything works fine.
But the problem is websocket is not working.
I need it for streaming response and it says this error.

[image]

Please help me how I can fix this issue.

I've tried to add this to the server.
[image]

If you see error, websocket connection is to [www.aitechly.com:3000/ws](http://www.aitechly.com:3000/ws) so I set location /ws/ and listen to the port 3000.

But when I try to restart nginx with this configuration, it says this error.

[image]

Also, I tried to change websocket port to default 80(not 3000), but I can't find how I can change it on React.

I don't know what to do now.
Please suggest me any solution that can make websocket works.

Comment: Your backend application has to be reconfigured to use a URL without the port in order for it to properly connect on port 443.  I.E. your backend is appending port 3000 to the request URL, it needs to not do that.  Then it will serve proper websockets and expect them to originate via the NGINX gateway.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I think webpack adds 3000 port as default to the websocket.
how can I change it?